# Lazy initialization for free

Tags: java, jvm, singleton, lazy-initialization, double-checked-locking

In an [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2001/jw-0209-double.html?page=5) on the double-checked locking idiom, I found this quote:

> One special case of lazy initialization that does work as expected without synchronization is the static singleton. When the initialized object is **a static field of a class with no other methods or fields**, the JVM effectively performs lazy initialization automatically.

Why is the emphasized part important? Why doesn't it work if there *are* other methods or fields?

(The article is already more than 10 years old. Is the information still relevant?)

Comment: +1 interesting question. Initially my guess would have been that that is the only time the JVM can be sure there won't be a call on that object before it is referenced from outside the class; but that doesn't seem to illuminate anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What it means is probably that, if a class has no other methods or fields, then you only access it for the singleton, so the singleton is only created when demanded. Otherwise, for example

```
class Foo 
{
    public static final Foo foo = new Foo();

    public static int x() { return 0; }
}

class AnotherClass
{
    void test() 
    {
        print(Foo.x());
    }
}
```

here, `foo` was instantiated, though it was never asked for.

But it's ok to have private static methods/fields, so others won't trigger class initialization by accident.

Comment: *"a static field of a class with no other methods or fields"* - but in your example Foo **has** a method x()

Comment: Yes, because he was giving the counter-example to the case in the article, where the singleton isn't really lazy because it might be created before it is needed.

Comment: Ah okay, but in Singleton implementations, you typically only have one static method which returns the instance, and all other methods are non-static, right?